# Can I output PS Queries as CSV file?

Tags: csv, peoplesoft

I am new to PeopleSoft and wanted to know whether is it possible to output files as CSV from PS Queries, and if so how is this accomplished? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like yes.

Manually: You can download excel in the PIA and convert to CSV.

Automated: You can invoke the PS Query via PeopleCode

http://peoplesoftdotnet.blogspot.com/2015/05/run-query-using-peoplecode.html

via googling: [ps query object peoplecode](https://www.google.com/search?q=ps%20query%20object%20peoplecodde)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if run as a scheduled query, CSV may be one of your options (if enabled in the process definition and process scheduler.)